# Visual Studio Code Automatically Scrolls While Typing

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual studio code sometimes automatically scrolls line by line whenever a character is typed (letter, space, delete). This just happened, I never did certain configurations or installed new extensions. I using version 1.87

I tried reinstalling visual studio code and disabling all extensions. But the issue still exist

Comment: Probably need a .gif uploaded of whatever it is you are seeing.  And your settings.json added to the post.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I found
"editor.stickyScroll.maxLineCount" in user settings (JSON) then delete it. And now my Visual Studio code is running normally again

Comment: Ahh I thought it might be that. I think a recent update enable sticky scroll by default

Comment: I cannot repro. What did you set that setting to?